# fmincon SQP leaving feasible region

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

According to the [SQP documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html#f26684),

"**Strict Feasibility With Respect to Bounds**

The sqp algorithm takes every iterative step in the region constrained by bounds. Furthermore, finite difference steps also respect bounds. Bounds are not strict; a step can be exactly on a boundary. This strict feasibility can be beneficial when your objective function or nonlinear constraint functions are undefined or are complex outside the region constrained by bounds."

I am finding that this is not the case. In my code, I have the following:

```
   options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Display','iter','Algorithm','sqp', ...
          'SpecifyObjectiveGradient', false,'SpecifyConstraintGradient',false, ...
          'OptimalityTolerance', 1e-6, 'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 1e6, 'StepTolerance', 1e-6, 'MaxIterations', 1e6, 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-12,...
          'DerivativeCheck', 'off', 'FiniteDifferenceType', 'central', 'OutputFcn', @outfun);
   xP = fmincon(@(x)no_objective(x), xP(:), [], [], [], [], zeros(numel(xP), 1), ones(numel(xP), 1), @(x)constraint_combined(x), options);
   xP = fmincon(@(x)objective_orig(x), xP(:), [], [], [], [], zeros(numel(xP), 1), ones(numel(xP), 1), @(x)constraint_combined(x), options);
```

Here, `xP` is my decision vector, `constraint_combined` is some combined nonlinear constraints. `no_objective` is defined as

```
function [o, do] = no_objective(x)
       o = 0; 
       do = zeros(numel(x), 1);
 end
```

`objective_orig` is the objective I wish to minimize.

I perform two calls to guarantee I start the second call within a feasible region (and `xP` is chosen such that I know it's close and can find the feasible region).

Distressingly, even though the first call converges to a feasible point:

```
                                                            Norm of First-order
   Iter F-count            f(x) Feasibility  Steplength        step  optimality
      0      41    0.000000e+00   2.220e-16                           0.000e+00
the second call leaves the feasible region and becomes infeasible:

                                                             Norm of First-order
   Iter F-count            f(x) Feasibility  Steplength        step  optimality
      0      41    4.203397e+05   2.220e-16                           7.511e+05
      1     115    4.203386e+05   8.348e-01   7.731e-06   5.180e-06   7.511e+05
      2     191    4.203376e+05   1.544e+00   3.788e-06   4.783e-06   7.502e+05
      3     269    4.203373e+05   1.772e+00   1.856e-06   2.063e-06   7.500e+05
      4     342    4.203364e+05   2.679e+00   1.104e-05   1.161e-05   7.495e+05
      5     379    4.203364e+05   2.679e+00   1.856e-06   1.654e-06   7.495e+05
```

This breaks the guarantees of MATLAB's SQP algorithm! I even have finite differences (as seen in the options above) set on, so that can't be the problem according to MATLAB's documentation.

What is going on here? How can this possibly happen?

(Apologies as this is cross-posted to MATLAB Answers, but the only view on that site so far is me, and SO seems to be a bit more active/better at getting eyeballs.)

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking, but may be you are confusing feasibility wrt bounds and feasibility wrt constraints. If x is feasible wrt to its bounds, it still may be violating the constraints.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah, you're right, I completely misread that.  At the risk of slightly derailing my own question, are there any algorithms that MATLAB has that guarantee feasibility if initialized at a feasible point?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know whether Matlab has a feasible path solver. An excellent large scale, feasible path solver is CONOPT (not sure if it has been hooked up to Matlab).

Comment: SQP can go along a path with INfeasible constraints and end up feasible. Scipy / NLopt SLSQP worked well on MOPTA08, a problem with linear objective, 124 variables, and 68 nonlinear constraints; don't know how similar it is to Matlab SQP.